# How to replace lost jars in Sonatype Nexus repository?

Tags: nexus

We have a Nexus repo which seems to have suddenly lost some of our common external dependency jars. We're trying to figure out why, and in the meantime we need to get them back so our builds succeed. Some other artifacts for a given dependency are still there (docs jars, sha1, and such).

What are some reasons for the sudden disappearance of our dependencies?

How can we get Nexus to re-download them?

Comment: As it turns out we had used up all the file handles when it tried to grab the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nexus will automatically redownload any components that are available in external proxy repositories.

And in terms of the components getting lost I suspect some external access to the storage.

Comment: Thanks, they were after a while. Is there anyway to kick that off?

Comment: Any external request e.g. from a build tools will trigger it. And you can set the expiration settings to lower time frames.

Comment: Hmmm, it seemed like it had blacklisted the attempt to download for a time after many failed attempts. I'm not sure what exactly I was seeing.

Comment: Maybe the remote repository was unavailable and that caused it to get blacklisted and it did not yet have the components. Hard to tell retrospectively.

Comment: Yeah, I knew even as I wrote this question that it might not have an answer, but the community is so good and my understanding of Nexus so limited that I thought it was worth a try. Thanks Manfred.